# Can I register an app with Spring Cloud Data Flow from ftp server?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am trying to register a spring cloud task jar which is residing in a ftp server ,  from a spring cloud data flow container which is running on PCF.

Can somebody help me in terms of how to do a "app register" from a ftp location from SCDF if SCDF supports that  ? How do i register a ftp location as remote repository with user name & passwd ?

Thanks!
Nilanjan

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the email, currently, in SCDF, we support `file://`, `maven://`, `http://`, `docker://`, and `hdfs://` as the file resolution strategies. Besides, for cloud platforms, it'd be recommended that you resolve and register artifacts from maven or docker to be more resilient.

If you're running SCDF on PCF, you could bind the SCDF-server to [volume-services](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-11/services/volume-services.html). By having all the custom apps in volume-services, SCDF-server could then resolve artifacts from the designated directory via `file://` resolution - this is another good alternative for PCF deployments.

Comment: Volume-services is a great option! . i will explore this. Thanks !